# Print records from log file using perl and hash data structure

Tags: perl, logging, hash, output

I have the following script, originally written by @zdim and I tweaked it a bit.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $file = "/home/tsec/prototype/logs/extractedlogs/cowrieresult.log";
open (LOG, $file);

# Assemble results for required output in data structure:
# %rept = { $port => { $usr => { $status => $freq } };

my %testhash;#new code
my %rept;
my ($ip, $port);

while (my $line = <LOG>)
{
    if ($line =~ /New connection/) {
        ($ip, $port) = $line =~ /New connection:\s+([^:]+):(\d+)/;
        #new code here
        if($ip){
                $testhash{$ip}++;
        }
        #end
        next;
    }

    my ($usr, $status) =  $line =~ m/login\ attempt \s+ \[ ( [^\]]+ ) \] \s+ (\w+)/x;
    if ($usr and $status) {
        $rept{$port}{$usr}{$status}++;
    }
    else { warn "Line with an unexpected format:\n$line" }
}
#close(LOG);
#open (LOG, $file);
#my $frequency = 0;
#while (my $line = <LOG>){
#       if($line =~ /login attempt/){

        #split string, get the ip and match it with original $ip
#       my ($testip) = (split /[\s,:\[\]\/]+/, $line)[-6];
        #print "$testip\n";
        #this two lines above print ips from login attempt line.
#       if($testip =~ /$ip/){
#               $frequency++;
#       }
        #elsif($testip =~ /^(?!$ip)/) {
                # stop frequency counter and start another one?
        #       print "$frequency\n";
        #       $frequency = 0;
        #}

#       }
#}
#print "$frequency\n";
#close(LOG);

#new code
print "ConnectionsOnIP\n";
foreach my $ip (sort keys %testhash){
        print "$testhash{$ip}\n";
}

print "\n";

#new code
print "Port,Status,AttemptOnPort,AttemptsOnIP,Malicious\n";
foreach my $ip (sort keys %testhash){
foreach my $port (sort keys %rept) {
    foreach my $usr (sort keys %{$rept{$port}}) {
        foreach my $stat ( sort keys %{$rept{$port}{$usr}} ) {
                if($port ne ""){
            print "$port,$stat,$rept{$port}{$usr}{$stat},$testhash{$ip}\n";
                }
        }
   }

}
}
#new code
```

As can be seen, I want to have the desired output which is working at the moment except for the last variable(AttemptsOnIP) I want the AttemptsOnIP variable to do what the AttemptsOnPort does to some extent:

```
Port,Status,AttemptsOnPort,ConnectionsOnIP,Malicious
15853,failed,4,18
15853,succeeded,4,18
18693,failed,1,18
18942,failed,1,18
18942,succeeded,1,18
31130,succeeded,1,18
43041,failed,1,18
43041,succeeded,1,18
46321,failed,1,18
46321,succeeded,1,18
47417,failed,3,18
47417,succeeded,3,18
48713,failed,1,18
48713,succeeded,1,18
53653,failed,1,18
53653,succeeded,1,18
60563,failed,1,18
60563,succeeded,1,18
```

I created a hash called testhash and passed it the ip variable to increment it. Now I want to increment this hashed variable depending on the IP of a single line of output. This is the logfile:

```
2016-05-02 10:20:56+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,14,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/!@] failed
2016-05-02 10:20:57+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,15,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/!@] failed
2016-05-02 10:20:57+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,14,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/123456] succeeded
2016-05-02 10:20:58+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,15,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/123456] succeeded
2016-05-02 10:43:32+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 183.3.202.172:55157 (172.17.0.5:2222) [session: 43283650]
2016-05-02 10:43:46+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 183.3.202.172:10319 (172.17.0.5:2222) [session: c7702f86]
2016-05-02 10:43:53+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 183.3.202.172:46321 (172.17.0.5:2222) [session: fe7bb804]
2016-05-02 10:43:57+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,17,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/!@] failed
2016-05-02 10:43:58+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,17,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/123456] succeeded
2016-05-02 10:43:59+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 183.3.202.172:18693 (172.17.0.5:2222) [session: d74eae96]
2016-05-02 10:44:02+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,18,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/!@] failed
2016-05-02 10:44:03+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 183.3.202.172:31130 (172.17.0.5:2222) [session: 3bde7820]
2016-05-02 10:44:03+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,18,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/123456] succeeded
2016-05-02 10:44:05+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 183.3.202.172:47417 (172.17.0.5:2222) [session: 3e177c02]
2016-05-02 10:44:06+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,19,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/!@] failed
2016-05-02 10:44:09+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,19,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/123456] succeeded
2016-05-02 10:44:10+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,21,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/!@] failed
2016-05-02 10:44:11+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,21,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/123456] succeeded
2016-05-02 10:44:13+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,20,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/!@] failed
2016-05-02 10:44:14+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,20,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/123456] succeeded
2016-05-02 11:06:55+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 183.3.202.172:13849 (172.17.0.5:2222) [session: b20915b6]
2016-05-02 11:07:06+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 183.3.202.172:61338 (172.17.0.5:2222) [session: cd38fe51]
2016-05-02 11:07:14+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 183.3.202.172:23048 (172.17.0.5:2222) [session: 01b12825]
2016-05-02 11:07:21+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 183.3.202.172:60563 (172.17.0.5:2222) [session: ad64232b]
2016-05-02 11:07:26+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,23,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/!@] failed
2016-05-02 11:07:27+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,23,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/123456] succeeded
2016-05-02 11:07:33+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 183.3.202.172:53653 (172.17.0.5:2222) [session: 9c48415b]
2016-05-02 11:07:41+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,26,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/!@] failed
2016-05-02 11:07:47+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,26,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/123456] succeeded
2016-05-02 11:12:25+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 183.3.202.172:18942 (172.17.0.5:2222) [session: a4dc4901]
2016-05-02 11:12:34+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,27,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/!@] failed
2016-05-02 11:12:36+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,27,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/123456] succeeded
2016-05-02 11:32:40+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 183.3.202.172:40091 (172.17.0.5:2222) [session: aeb36234]
2016-05-02 11:32:43+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 183.3.202.172:53505 (172.17.0.5:2222) [session: 9022c831]
2016-05-02 11:32:48+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 183.3.202.172:15131 (172.17.0.5:2222) [session: cf62fb9a]
2016-05-02 11:32:48+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 183.3.202.172:15853 (172.17.0.5:2222) [session: f2f6c254]
2016-05-02 11:32:50+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,28,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/!@] failed
2016-05-02 11:32:52+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,28,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/123456] succeeded
2016-05-02 11:32:55+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,29,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/!@] failed
2016-05-02 11:32:55+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,30,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/!@] failed
2016-05-02 11:32:56+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,30,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/123456] succeeded
2016-05-02 11:32:57+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,31,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/!@] failed
2016-05-02 11:32:59+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,31,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/123456] succeeded
```

Therefore the output should be as follows for the first two lines

```
Port,Status,AttemptsOnPort,ConnectionsOnIP,Malicious
    15853,failed,4,(total no of times the IP using this port is seen in log, even if it used other ports)
    15853,succeeded,4,18
```

Comment: It seems that you need to add a counter for IP seen for each: user, status.  Thus you'd add a hash with those levels, with a counter, `$by_ip{$ip}{$usr}{$status}++`. You add this right alongside the `$rept{$port}{$usr}{$status}++`, on the next line.  This can use the `$ip` already captured, I don't see why you need to fetch it from the `last attempt` line again (has to be the same, no?).  Don't forget to declare this new hash, `my %by_ip`. I can post this, but try it yourself first and report back.  The way you have it now it counts IP for any port, user, status -- all of it, the lump sum.

Comment: @zdim not sure if I did it correctly, I added the hash exactly under the `$rept{$port}{$usr}{$status}++` and this is where I'm printing:

`print "Port,Status,AttemptOnPort,AttemptsOnIP,Malicious\n";
foreach my $ip (sort keys %by_ip){
foreach my $port (sort keys %rept) {
    foreach my $usr (sort keys %{$rept{$port}}) {
        foreach my $stat ( sort keys %{$rept{$port}{$usr}} ) {
                if($port ne ""){
            print "$port,$stat,$rept{$port}{$usr}{$stat},$by_ip{$ip}{$usr}{$stat},\n$
                }
        }
   }

}
}
`

Comment: @zdim this is the [output](http://pastebin.com/XDLbmBAK) I'm getting

Comment: Alright, I see.  After adding the line you have two _distinct_ data structures (albeit being very similar). Nested iteration that you try is tricky and may well double some things while mismatching others.  I'll look into it. (Maybe a slight modification of code would make it easier to extract needed output.)

Comment: @zdim Yes in fact that is exactly what is happening, double data and raising some errors. If you can kindly point out how I can do this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am really really close as you can see on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/nDKgcjP2)
The problem is that I want that for AttemptsonIP, 1 is associated with the IP 181.3.202.142 using port 44444.

Comment: @zdin And any other port that uses that IP. So if there were two other entries with `New connection` on same IP and/or same port 44444 or 55555, the output would be for this IP example

`Port,Status,AttemptOnPort,AttemptsOnIP,Malicious
44444,X,X,3,
55555,X,X,3,
53653,X,X,18` where X represents other not important values and 3 & 18 represent total no an IP was spotted in logfile. So IP 1 used 1st 2nd ports and appeared 3 times. IP 2 18

Comment: I _will_ post an answer to this question, probably tonight.  Your newest post seems to repeat this ... ?  (Or am I misunderstanding it?)

Comment: @zdim Yes it repeats it. Ok will hear from you tonight

Comment: OK ... for the future: _never do that_.  Do not post questions that are similar to others, or -- _gasp_ -- the same.  There is a name for that, "_duplicate_", and it's not a good thing.  I do not mean to make you feel bad with this, just a note for the future.  Ideally, you'd articulate a _good_ question, and then you _surely_ get great responses. If it turns out the question isn't good enough, it is hard to tell what is better -- significant change or a new one. (Little clarifications are often needed and OK.) _So: put a question together well to start with._

Comment: Let me know how my post works for what you need, I wasn't sure about some things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code prints a report in the following format. Remove `(IP)` field if undesired.

```
Port,Status,AttemptOnPort,(IP),ConnectionsOnIP
```

Such a line is printed for each user.  However, `ConnectionsOnIP` is the total number of this IP being seen for *all* users and ports. The code also prints a separate report on IP's alone. See comments about related questions.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = 'logfile.txt';
open my $fh_in, '<', $file;

# Assemble results for required output in data structure:
# %rept = {
#    $port => {
#       $ip => {
#           $usr => { 
#               $status => $freq 
#          },
#       },
#   },
# };
# Auxiliary: %ip_tot = { $ip => { $status => $freq } } 

my (%rept, %ip_tot);
my ($ip, $port);

while (my $line = <$fh_in>) 
{
    if ($line =~ /New connection/) {
        ($ip, $port) = $line =~ /New connection:\s+([^:]+):(\d+)/;
        next;
    }   
    elsif (!$ip or !$port) { next }  # First lines come before New connection

    my ($usr, $status) = $line =~ m/login attempt\s+\[([^\]]+)\]\s+(\w+)/;
    if ($usr and $status) {
        $rept{$port}{$ip}{$usr}{$status}++;
        $ip_tot{$ip}{$status}++;
    }   
    else { warn "Line with an unexpected format:\n$line" }
}

print "Port,Status,AttemptOnPort,(IP),ConnectionsOnIP\n";
foreach my $port (sort keys %rept) {
    foreach my $ip (sort keys %{$rept{$port}}) {
        foreach my $usr (sort keys %{$rept{$port}{$ip}}) {
            foreach my $stat ( sort keys %{$rept{$port}{$ip}{$usr}} ) { 
                print "$port,$stat,$rept{$port}{$ip}{$usr}{$stat}";
                print "$,(ip),$ip_tot{$ip}{$stat}\n"; 
            }   
        }   
    }   
}

print "\n";
print "IP,Status,Occurences\n";
foreach my $ip (sort keys %ip_tot) {
    foreach my $stat ( sort keys %{$ip_tot{$ip}} ) {
        print "$ip,$stat,$ip_tot{$ip}{$stat}\n"; 
    }
}
```

With the supplied input as `logfile.txt` this prints

```
Port,Status,AttemptOnPort,(IP),ConnectionsOnIP
15853,failed,4,(183.3.202.172),12
15853,succeeded,3,(183.3.202.172),11
18693,failed,1,(183.3.202.172),12
18942,failed,1,(183.3.202.172),12
18942,succeeded,1,(183.3.202.172),11
31130,succeeded,1,(183.3.202.172),11
46321,failed,1,(183.3.202.172),12
46321,succeeded,1,(183.3.202.172),11
47417,failed,3,(183.3.202.172),12
47417,succeeded,3,(183.3.202.172),11
53653,failed,1,(183.3.202.172),12
53653,succeeded,1,(183.3.202.172),11
60563,failed,1,(183.3.202.172),12
60563,succeeded,1,(183.3.202.172),11

IP,Status,Occurences
183.3.202.172,failed,12
183.3.202.172,succeeded,11
```

---

Regex explanation. This is valid code, courtesy of `/x`. The `\s+` are ignored in comments.

```
my ($usr, $status) =  $line =~ m/ 
    login\ attempt \s+         # literal, serves as a 'post' to help matching 
    \[                         # literal [ within which our pattern is 
        (                      # start capture 
            [^\]]+             # any char which is not ], 1 or more times  
        )                      # end of capture 
    \] \s+                     # closing literal ] 
    (\w+)                      # next capture: any 'word' char, 1 or more times 
/x;
```

In the heart of this is the *negated character class*, `[ ^\] ]`. It says: match any one character (`[...]`) that is *not* (`^`) a bracket (`\]`), which needs to be escaped (`\`) to mean the literal character. The `+` behind it means *one-or-more* times. For example

```
my $str = 'a5_".-]B1'; 
if ($str =~ m/([^\]]+)/) { say "Got: $1" }
```

This prints `Got: a5_".-`. Everything up to the first `]` is matched (and captured). This is one way to specify a *non-greedy match*, going up to *the first* occurrence of the given character.  Note that something like `.+]` would match everything up to the *last* `]`, it is *greedy*.

See [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html). Search SO, both for specific questions and for mini-tutorials.