# Misinterpretation with hashes in perl, populating from log file

Tags: perl, hash, hashset, logfile

Below you can find the output on screen and the source code generating the problem

```
Use of uninitialized value $port in hash element at ./test3.prg line 26, <LOG> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $port in hash element at ./test3.prg line 26, <LOG> line 2.
Use of uninitialized value $port in hash element at ./test3.prg line 26, <LOG> line 3.
Use of uninitialized value $port in hash element at ./test3.prg line 26, <LOG> line 4.
AttemptsOnIP
181.3.202.142,1
183.3.202.172,18

Port,Status,AttemptOnPort,AttemptsOnIP,Malicious
15853,failed,4,1,
15853,succeeded,4,1,
18693,failed,1,1,
18942,failed,1,1,
18942,succeeded,1,1,
31130,succeeded,1,1,
43041,failed,1,1,
43041,succeeded,1,1,
44444,failed,1,1,
46321,failed,1,1,
46321,succeeded,1,1,
47417,failed,3,1,
47417,succeeded,3,1,
48713,failed,1,1,
48713,succeeded,1,1,
53653,failed,1,1,
53653,succeeded,1,1,
60563,failed,1,1,
60563,succeeded,1,1,
15853,failed,4,18,
15853,succeeded,4,18,
18693,failed,1,18,
18942,failed,1,18,
18942,succeeded,1,18,
31130,succeeded,1,18,
43041,failed,1,18,
43041,succeeded,1,18,
44444,failed,1,18,
46321,failed,1,18,
46321,succeeded,1,18,
47417,failed,3,18,
47417,succeeded,3,18,
48713,failed,1,18,
48713,succeeded,1,18,
53653,failed,1,18,
53653,succeeded,1,18,
60563,failed,1,18,
60563,succeeded,1,18,
```

This is the code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $file = "/home/tsec/prototype/logs/extractedlogs/cowrieresult.log";
open (LOG, $file);

# Assemble results for required output in data structure:
# %rept = { $port => { $usr => { $status => $freq } };

my %by_ip;#new code
my %rept;
my ($ip, $port);

while (my $line = <LOG>)
{
    if ($line =~ /New connection/) {
        ($ip, $port) = $line =~ /New connection:\s+([^:]+):(\d+)/;
        $by_ip{$ip}++;
        next;
    }

    my ($usr, $status) =  $line =~ m/login\ attempt \s+ \[ ( [^\]]+ ) \] \s+ (\w+)/x;
    if ($usr and $status) {
        $rept{$port}{$usr}{$status}++;
        #$by_ip{$ip}{$usr}{$status}++; # first 4 lines in log dont have ip and port
        # since they are login attempt not new connection.
    }
    else { warn "Line with an unexpected format:\n$line" }
}
#close(LOG);
#open (LOG, $file);
#my $frequency = 0;
#while (my $line = <LOG>){
#       if($line =~ /login attempt/){

        #split string, get the ip and match it with original $ip
#       my ($testip) = (split /[\s,:\[\]\/]+/, $line)[-6];
        #print "$testip\n";
        #this two lines above print ips from login attempt line.
#       if($testip =~ /$ip/){
#               $frequency++;
#       }
        #elsif($testip =~ /^(?!$ip)/) {
                # stop frequency counter and start another one?
        #       print "$frequency\n";
        #       $frequency = 0;
        #}

#       }
#}
#print "$frequency\n";
#close(LOG);

#new code
print "AttemptsOnIP\n";
#foreach my $ip (sort keys %by_ip){
#       foreach my $usr (sort keys %{$by_ip{$ip}}){
#               foreach my $status (sort keys %{$rept{$usr}}){
#                       print "$ip,$by_ip{$ip}{$usr}{$status}\n";
#               }
#       }
#}

#new code
foreach my $ip (sort keys %by_ip){
        print "$ip,$by_ip{$ip}\n";
}

print "\n";

#new code
print "Port,Status,AttemptOnPort,AttemptsOnIP,Malicious\n";
foreach my $ip (sort keys %by_ip){
foreach my $port (sort keys %rept) {
    foreach my $usr (sort keys %{$rept{$port}}) {
        foreach my $stat ( sort keys %{$rept{$port}{$usr}} ) {
                if($port ne ""){

                           print "$port,$stat,$rept{$port}{$usr}{$stat},$by_ip{$ip},\n";

                }
        }
   }

}
}
#new code
```

And this is the logfile that I have

```
2016-05-02 10:20:56+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,14,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/!@] failed
2016-05-02 10:20:57+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,15,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/!@] failed
2016-05-02 10:20:57+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,14,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/123456] succeeded
2016-05-02 10:20:58+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,15,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/123456] succeeded
2016-05-02 10:43:32+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 183.3.202.172:55157 (172.17.0.5:2222) [session: 43283650]
2016-05-02 10:43:46+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 183.3.202.172:10319 (172.17.0.5:2222) [session: c7702f86]
2016-05-02 10:43:53+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 183.3.202.172:46321 (172.17.0.5:2222) [session: fe7bb804]
2016-05-02 10:43:57+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,17,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/!@] failed
2016-05-02 10:43:58+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,17,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/123456] succeeded
2016-05-02 10:43:59+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 183.3.202.172:18693 (172.17.0.5:2222) [session: d74eae96]
2016-05-02 10:44:02+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,18,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/!@] failed
2016-05-02 10:44:03+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 183.3.202.172:31130 (172.17.0.5:2222) [session: 3bde7820]
2016-05-02 10:44:03+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,18,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/123456] succeeded
2016-05-02 10:44:05+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 183.3.202.172:47417 (172.17.0.5:2222) [session: 3e177c02]
2016-05-02 10:44:06+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,19,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/!@] failed
2016-05-02 10:44:09+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,19,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/123456] succeeded
2016-05-02 10:44:10+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,21,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/!@] failed
2016-05-02 10:44:11+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,21,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/123456] succeeded
2016-05-02 10:44:13+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,20,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/!@] failed
2016-05-02 10:44:14+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,20,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/123456] succeeded
2016-05-02 11:06:55+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 183.3.202.172:13849 (172.17.0.5:2222) [session: b20915b6]
2016-05-02 11:07:06+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 183.3.202.172:61338 (172.17.0.5:2222) [session: cd38fe51]
2016-05-02 11:07:14+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 183.3.202.172:23048 (172.17.0.5:2222) [session: 01b12825]
2016-05-02 11:07:21+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 183.3.202.172:60563 (172.17.0.5:2222) [session: ad64232b]
2016-05-02 11:07:26+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,23,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/!@] failed
2016-05-02 11:07:27+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,23,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/123456] succeeded
2016-05-02 11:07:33+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 183.3.202.172:53653 (172.17.0.5:2222) [session: 9c48415b]
2016-05-02 11:07:41+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,26,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/!@] failed
2016-05-02 11:07:47+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,26,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/123456] succeeded
2016-05-02 11:12:25+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 183.3.202.172:18942 (172.17.0.5:2222) [session: a4dc4901]
2016-05-02 11:12:34+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,27,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/!@] failed
2016-05-02 11:12:36+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,27,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/123456] succeeded
2016-05-02 11:32:40+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 183.3.202.172:40091 (172.17.0.5:2222) [session: aeb36234]
2016-05-02 11:32:43+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 183.3.202.172:53505 (172.17.0.5:2222) [session: 9022c831]
2016-05-02 11:32:48+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 183.3.202.172:15131 (172.17.0.5:2222) [session: cf62fb9a]
2016-05-02 11:32:48+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 183.3.202.172:15853 (172.17.0.5:2222) [session: f2f6c254]
2016-05-02 11:32:50+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,28,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/!@] failed
2016-05-02 11:32:52+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,28,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/123456] succeeded
2016-05-02 11:32:55+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,29,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/!@] failed
2016-05-02 11:32:55+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,30,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/!@] failed
2016-05-02 11:32:56+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,30,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/123456] succeeded
2016-05-02 11:32:57+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,31,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/!@] failed
2016-05-02 11:32:59+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,31,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/123456] succeeded
2016-05-02 11:33:04+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,29,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/123456] succeeded
2016-05-02 11:33:07+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 183.3.202.172:48713 (172.17.0.5:2222) [session: e1544c90]
2016-05-02 11:33:15+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,32,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/!@] failed
2016-05-02 11:33:18+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,32,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/123456] succeeded
2016-05-02 11:33:19+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 183.3.202.172:43041 (172.17.0.5:2222) [session: 383f328c]
2016-05-02 11:33:25+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,33,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/!@] failed
2016-05-02 11:33:26+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,33,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/123456] succeeded
2016-05-02 11:33:19+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 181.3.202.142:44444 (172.17.0.5:2222) [session: 383f328c]
2016-05-02 11:33:25+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,33,181.3.202.142] login attempt [root/xyz] failed
```

So basically, I want ports that are associated with IP X to have the total number of occurrences that IP has in the log file.

So for instance I want this output with no repeating entries, unlike as shown in Pastebin

```
15853,failed,4,18,
15853,succeeded,4,18,
18693,failed,1,18,
18942,failed,1,18,
18942,succeeded,1,18,
31130,succeeded,1,18,
43041,failed,1,18,
43041,succeeded,1,18,
44444,failed,1,1, -> Since it is seen only once in logfile
46321,failed,1,18,
46321,succeeded,1,18,
47417,failed,3,18,
47417,succeeded,3,18,
48713,failed,1,18,
48713,succeeded,1,18,
53653,failed,1,18,
53653,succeeded,1,18,
60563,failed,1,18,
60563,succeeded,1,18,
```

UPDATE: Migrated everything from paste bin to the post. I also want to get rid of the uninitialized value port

Comment: Isn't this a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36992311/print-records-from-log-file-using-perl-and-hash-data-structure)?

Comment: @MattJacob yes but this is more updated and maybe better explained

Answer (score 0):

Your output has the following fields:

```
Port,Status,AttemptOnPort,AttemptsOnIP,Malicious
```

Of those, the following form the grouping key:

```
Port,Status
```

Yet your hash is keyed by

```
Port,User,Status
```

So the first thing you must do is adjust the structure of `%rept`.

---

You are also repeating the results for each IP address.

The second thing you must do is remove that extra loop.

---

The following is a cleaned up version of your code with the changes mentioned above:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my %by_ip;
my %rept;
my $prev_port;
while (<DATA>) {
    if (my ($ip, $port) = /New connection:\s+([^:]+):(\d+)/) {
        ++$by_ip{$ip};
        $prev_port = $port;
    }
    elsif ( my ($usr, $status) = /login \s+ attempt \s+ \[ ( [^\]]+ ) \] \s+ (\w+)/x ) {
        ++$rept{$prev_port}{$status}
            if defined($prev_port);
    }
    else {
        warn("Line with an unexpected format: $_");
    }
}

print(join(',', qw( IP AttemptsOnIP )), "\n");
for my $ip (sort keys(%by_ip)) {
    print(join(',', $ip, $by_ip{$ip}), "\n");
}

print("\n");

print(join(',', qw( Port Status AttemptOnPort AttemptsOnIP Malicious )), "\n");
for my $port (sort keys(%rept)) {
    for my $status (sort keys(%{$rept{$port}})) {
        print(join(',', $port, $status, $rept{$port}{$status}, '???', '???'), "\n");
    }
}

__DATA__
2016-05-02 10:20:56+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,14,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/!@] failed
2016-05-02 10:20:57+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,15,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/!@] failed
2016-05-02 10:20:57+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,14,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/123456] succeeded
2016-05-02 10:20:58+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,15,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/123456] succeeded
2016-05-02 10:43:32+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 183.3.202.172:55157 (172.17.0.5:2222) [session: 43283650]
2016-05-02 10:43:46+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 183.3.202.172:10319 (172.17.0.5:2222) [session: c7702f86]
2016-05-02 10:43:53+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 183.3.202.172:46321 (172.17.0.5:2222) [session: fe7bb804]
2016-05-02 10:43:57+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,17,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/!@] failed
2016-05-02 10:43:58+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,17,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/123456] succeeded
2016-05-02 10:43:59+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 183.3.202.172:18693 (172.17.0.5:2222) [session: d74eae96]
2016-05-02 10:44:02+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,18,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/!@] failed
2016-05-02 10:44:03+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 183.3.202.172:31130 (172.17.0.5:2222) [session: 3bde7820]
2016-05-02 10:44:03+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,18,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/123456] succeeded
2016-05-02 10:44:05+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 183.3.202.172:47417 (172.17.0.5:2222) [session: 3e177c02]
2016-05-02 10:44:06+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,19,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/!@] failed
2016-05-02 10:44:09+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,19,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/123456] succeeded
2016-05-02 10:44:10+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,21,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/!@] failed
2016-05-02 10:44:11+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,21,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/123456] succeeded
2016-05-02 10:44:13+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,20,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/!@] failed
2016-05-02 10:44:14+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,20,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/123456] succeeded
2016-05-02 11:06:55+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 183.3.202.172:13849 (172.17.0.5:2222) [session: b20915b6]
2016-05-02 11:07:06+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 183.3.202.172:61338 (172.17.0.5:2222) [session: cd38fe51]
2016-05-02 11:07:14+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 183.3.202.172:23048 (172.17.0.5:2222) [session: 01b12825]
2016-05-02 11:07:21+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 183.3.202.172:60563 (172.17.0.5:2222) [session: ad64232b]
2016-05-02 11:07:26+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,23,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/!@] failed
2016-05-02 11:07:27+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,23,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/123456] succeeded
2016-05-02 11:07:33+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 183.3.202.172:53653 (172.17.0.5:2222) [session: 9c48415b]
2016-05-02 11:07:41+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,26,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/!@] failed
2016-05-02 11:07:47+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,26,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/123456] succeeded
2016-05-02 11:12:25+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 183.3.202.172:18942 (172.17.0.5:2222) [session: a4dc4901]
2016-05-02 11:12:34+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,27,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/!@] failed
2016-05-02 11:12:36+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,27,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/123456] succeeded
2016-05-02 11:32:40+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 183.3.202.172:40091 (172.17.0.5:2222) [session: aeb36234]
2016-05-02 11:32:43+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 183.3.202.172:53505 (172.17.0.5:2222) [session: 9022c831]
2016-05-02 11:32:48+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 183.3.202.172:15131 (172.17.0.5:2222) [session: cf62fb9a]
2016-05-02 11:32:48+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 183.3.202.172:15853 (172.17.0.5:2222) [session: f2f6c254]
2016-05-02 11:32:50+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,28,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/!@] failed
2016-05-02 11:32:52+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,28,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/123456] succeeded
2016-05-02 11:32:55+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,29,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/!@] failed
2016-05-02 11:32:55+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,30,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/!@] failed
2016-05-02 11:32:56+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,30,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/123456] succeeded
2016-05-02 11:32:57+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,31,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/!@] failed
2016-05-02 11:32:59+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,31,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/123456] succeeded
2016-05-02 11:33:04+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,29,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/123456] succeeded
2016-05-02 11:33:07+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 183.3.202.172:48713 (172.17.0.5:2222) [session: e1544c90]
2016-05-02 11:33:15+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,32,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/!@] failed
2016-05-02 11:33:18+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,32,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/123456] succeeded
2016-05-02 11:33:19+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 183.3.202.172:43041 (172.17.0.5:2222) [session: 383f328c]
2016-05-02 11:33:25+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,33,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/!@] failed
2016-05-02 11:33:26+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,33,183.3.202.172] login attempt [root/123456] succeeded
2016-05-02 11:33:19+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 181.3.202.142:44444 (172.17.0.5:2222) [session: 383f328c]
2016-05-02 11:33:25+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,33,181.3.202.142] login attempt [root/xyz] failed
```

Output:

```
AttemptsOnIP
181.3.202.142,1
183.3.202.172,18

Port,Status,AttemptOnPort,AttemptsOnIP,Malicious
15853,failed,4,???,???
15853,succeeded,4,???,???
18693,failed,1,???,???
18942,failed,1,???,???
18942,succeeded,1,???,???
31130,succeeded,1,???,???
43041,failed,1,???,???
43041,succeeded,1,???,???
44444,failed,1,???,???
46321,failed,1,???,???
46321,succeeded,1,???,???
47417,failed,3,???,???
47417,succeeded,3,???,???
48713,failed,1,???,???
48713,succeeded,1,???,???
53653,failed,1,???,???
53653,succeeded,1,???,???
60563,failed,1,???,???
60563,succeeded,1,???,???
```

Comment: For the first set of `???`, under attempts on IP,  in each entry I need to have the total frequency of the occurrences of that IP where that port makes use of that IP. As shown in my post `43041,succeeded,1,18,
44444,failed,1,1, -> Since it is seen only once in logfile
46321,failed,1,18,
46321,succeeded,1,18,`

Comment: @firepro20, That makes no sense. No IP address is associated with the row. Maybe you want `**IP**,Port,Status,**AttemptsOnIp**,**AttemptsOnIpAndPort**`? (Note that there will be duplicated data if you do that, which is why it's better to use two tables are you are already doing.)

Comment: So there is no way to associate first and second table so that the frequency 1,18 is assigned accordingly to each of the ports in the second table under colomn `AttemptsOnIP`?

Comment: The two tables have no fields in common. How do you propose to associate them. In other words, when should a row in the second table use `1` and when should it use `18`?

Comment: When an IP is using many src ports, thus the srcport outputted in second table can be associated with 1 or 18. A checker of some sort.

Comment: I'd that suppose to be an answer to my question? When should a row in the second table use `1` and when should it use `18`?